# How can i get the time in ping?

Tags: android, ping

I use this code to ping the website google.com

```
    public String ping(String url) {
       String str = "";
       try {
           Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                   "/system/bin/ping -c 1 " + url);
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                   process.getInputStream()));

           int i;
           char[] buffer = new char[4096];
           StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

           while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
               output.append(buffer, 0, i);
           reader.close();

           // body.append(output.toString()+"\n");
           str = output.toString();
           Log.d("str", str);
       }
       catch (IOException e) {
           // body.append("Error\n");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return str;
   }
```

The log-cat output looks like that:

```
11-12 07:23:34.028: D/str(1399): PING www.google.com (216.58.209.196) 56(84) bytes of data. 
11-12 07:23:34.028: D/str(1399): 64 bytes from bud02s22-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.209.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48
**time=149 ms** 
11-12 07:23:34.028: D/str(1399): --- www.google.com ping statistics --- 
11-12 07:23:34.028: D/str(1399): 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms 
11-12 07:23:34.028: D/str(1399): rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 149.750/149.750/149.750/0.000 ms
```

Have anyone and idea how I can just get the "time=149 ms" value?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a string. There are plenty of questions (and answers) here how to extract a number from a string.

Comment: thanks @GeraldSchneider i will check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
/.*time=([0-9]+)\s(ms).*/
```

The information you want is in the two capturing groups. The reason I  am recommending regex is because if you want some other information, you can easily extend this.

`sed` example of above (`d` contains your string):

```
prakhar@inS4n3 /tmp $ cat d| sed -r 's/.*?time=([0-9]+)\s(ms).*/\1 \2/'
149 ms
```

Here's how to use the above in java: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm.

Comment: Hi, the time may be float,so I use "(time=)(.*?)(ms)" as the regex.

Answer (score 0):

use [String. indexOf (String subString, int start)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method to find all the "time=" substrings in the str variable, and get the digits after every "time=" substring.
Or use ReqularExpression [read here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your case try this:

```
    try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 " + url);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            int i;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

            while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
                output.append(buffer, 0, i);
            reader.close();

            // body.append(output.toString()+"\n");
            str = output.toString();

            if (str.contentEquals("time=")) {
                str = str.substring(str.indexOf("time="), str.length());
                Log.d("str", str);
            }
        }
```